# $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2x-x\tan x}{x^4}$

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

fine the limit :

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2x-x\tan x}{x^4}$$

My Try :

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2x-x\tan x}{x^4}\\\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin x \sin x}{x}-\frac{x\tan x}{x}}{x^4/x}\\\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x -\tan x}{x^3}=-1/2 $$

is it right ?

Comment: No.  All the $x$'s have to go to zero at the same time and at the same rate.  In your second last line, you can cancel the $x$'s on $\tan x$, but you can't let the $x$ in $\sin x/x$ go to $0$ before the other $x$'s.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\dfrac{\sin^2x-x\tan x}{x^4}=\dfrac{\sin x}{x\cos x}\cdot\dfrac{\sin x\cos x-x}{x^3}$$

Set $2x=y$ to get $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x\cos x-x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin2x-2x}{2x^3}=4\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin y-y}{y^3}$$

Now see [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion)

Answer (score 1):

Another hint, write
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sin^2 x - x\tan x}{x^4} = \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\frac{\sin(2x) - 2x}{x^2\sin(2x)}
\end{equation}
In the limit $x \rightarrow 0$, $\sin(2x) - 2x = -4x^3/3$. You can confirm using Mathematica that your answer $-2/3$ is indeed correct.